# Graph of n vertices such that its diameter is 3 and the diameter of the complement is also 3?

Tags: algorithm, math, graph

Is it possible to have such a graph for every n? If so, is it possible to generate such a graph programatically?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What work have you done on this problem so far? And what kind of graph generation do you mean: an adjacency matrix, graphical, or other?

Comment: Diameter exactly 3?

Comment: This is part of a bigger problem and I have reduced it to the case when the diameter equals 3 (exactly 3) but I don't know how to go about this case.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1929512/if-the-diameter-of-graph-is-greater-than-3-then-the-diameter-of-its-complement-g

Comment: @DmitryBychenko yes, I've read that, thank you; but it does not answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible for **n** < 4, as you need at least 4 nodes to create a distance of 3.

But for **n** >= 4 it is always possible.

You could choose any vertices **A**, **B** and **C** and have edges between **A** and all other vertices, except **C**, and have one more edge between **B** and **C**. This can be visualised as follows:

[image]

Assume in what follows that **D** is any vertex that is not equal to **A**, **B** or **C**. As we have at least 4 vertices, there is at least such a vertex.

#### This graph has a distance of 3

This is because every pair of vertices, not including **C**, represents a distance of at most 2, as these vertices are connected via **A**. **C** can only reach other vertices via the path **B**, **A**, which represents a distance of 3 when the target is **D**.

Therefore the distance is 3.

#### The complement graph has a distance of 3

In the complement graph the distance between...:

- **A** and **C** is 1
- **B** and **D** is 1
- **C** and **D** is 1
- **A** and **D** is 2 (via **C**)
- **B** and **C** is 2 (via **D**)
- **A** and **B** is 3 (via **C** and **D**)

This lists all possible unordered pairs with **A**, **B**, **C** and **D**. Then remain the distances represented by any pair which does not involve **A**, **B**, or **C**: such pairs are edges in the complement graph, and so they are at a distance of 1.

Therefore the distance of the complement graph is 3, and is represented by vertices **A** and **B**.

#### Program it

Given a list of vertices **V**, you could do it as follows (pseudo code, edges are represented as tuples of two vertices within parentheses):

```
a = V[0]
b = V[1]
c = V[2]
edges = [ (b,c) ]
for each d in V:
    if d != a && d != c:
        edges.append( (a,d) )
```